# What is a good alternative for distinct + find in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to make a query that outputs documents that have a certain element, but also only have another unique element, for example:

```
 Temp.find({ UId: UserID }).sort({ "created_at" : -1 }).exec( function (err, data) {
    console.log(data + "     " + err);
    callback(data);
  });
```

};
Returns this:

```
{
    "updatedAt": "2017-05-23T18:18:19.000Z",
    "created_at": "2017-05-23T18:18:19.000Z",
    "UId": "58f8954c3602b80552b6f1fb",
    "value": 69,
    "SerialNumber": "IIOJOIMJ",
    "_id": "59247cebd96d5406651c791e",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "updatedAt": "2017-05-23T16:34:22.000Z",
    "created_at": "2017-05-23T16:34:22.000Z",
    "UId": "58f8954c3602b80552b6f1fb",
    "value": 70,
    "SerialNumber": "IIOJOIMJ",
    "_id": "5924648e56628d005ad15f0e",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

But i want the query to only return distinct elements, so that only one of the 2 documents is returned.
I tried to do this like this:

```
Temp.find({ UId: UserID }).sort({ "created_at" : -1 }).distinct('SerialNumber', function (err, data) {

    console.log(data + "     " + err);
    callback(data);
  });
```

but that crashes my app. How can i best solve this?

Thanks!

EDIT

I looked at @gaganshera solution, and it works! but is it also possible to ge the rest of the document with it?

Comment: Specifying the Error message or stack trace could be useful.

Comment: Weird thing is that I don't get any, while i do ask for it

Answer (score 1):

Using the `distinct` function, you can specify the condition as well as the distinct column like this

```
Temp.distinct('SerialNumber', { UId: UserID })
```

Comment: Perfect! Do you perhaps know how i can show the rest of the document as well?